# Configuration with name 'compileClasspath' not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I migrate to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta3` and Gradle 4.1, I am seeing the following error:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.UnknownConfigurationException: Configuration with name 'compileClasspath' not found.
>               at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.createNotFoundException(DefaultConfigurationContainer.java:123)
>               at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.getByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:229)
>               at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.getByName(DefaultConfigurationContainer.java:113)
>               at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.getByName(DefaultConfigurationContainer.java:48)
>               at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleProject$ProjectSearch.getProject(LintGradleProject.java:884)
>               at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleProject$ProjectSearch.getProject(LintGradleProject.java:996)
>               at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleProject$ProjectSearch.getProject(LintGradleProject.java:785)
>               at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient.createLintRequest(LintGradleClient.java:193)
>               at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.java:151)
>               at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient.run(LintGradleClient.java:209)
>               at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.runLint(Lint.java:365)
>               at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lintSingleVariant(Lint.java:335)

---

Here is my directory structure:

```
android-db
  /db
    /build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  /android-common
    build.gradle
    /common
        build.gradle
```

---

`android-db/db/build.gradle` is the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
}

def jenkinsBuildNumber = {
    System.getenv().BUILD_NUMBER?.toInteger() ?: 999999
}

// Change this when we upgrade the library version
def buildVersion = {
    '1.0' + "." + jenkinsBuildNumber()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    implementation project(path: ':android-common:common', configuration: 'default')

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
    implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.5'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
}
```

---

`android-db/android-common/common/build.gradle` is the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
}


def jenkinsBuildNumber = {
    System.getenv().BUILD_NUMBER?.toInteger() ?: 999999
}

// Change this when we upgrade the library version
def buildVersion = {
    '1.0' + "." + jenkinsBuildNumber()
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '25.3.1'
    playServicesVersion = '10.2.6'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:seismic:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'


    // Unit testing dependencies
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use the Hamcrest matcher library
    //androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    // more stuff, e.g., Mockito
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3"
}
```

Comment: Same error here. It looks lint related

Answer (score 11):

Today I've solved the same problem! I've spent more than a week trying to find a solution.
In short Lint-plugin for Gradle implicitly supposes that you have the following section

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradlePluginVersion"
    }
}
```

in your root-level `build.gradle` file. Just move that common section from your scripts right to the root-level script.

Comment: Where did you find out that the Lint plugin expects this section in the root build.gradle?

Comment: If you mean documentation then I didn't find anything in it. I read sources of the plugin and found that. Besides experiments on the clean project proved my theory.

Comment: I'm also stuck on this issue; but this solution did not work for me.  So far, stumped - where did you find the sources of the plugin?

Comment: I already have this code in my build.gradle. however, I'm still getting this error

Answer (score 10):

Just add the compileClasspath as a **configuration** name to your **build.gradle**

```
configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```