# Error Configuration with name 'compileClasspath' not found while trying to create release apk after updating ExpoKit from SDk 32 to SDK 33

Tags: react-native, expo

I have updated ExpoKit SDK from 32 to 33 version and now, when I'm trying to create release apk, I'm getting an error:

```
Error Configuration with name 'compileClasspath' not found
```

Any ideas how is possible to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49541169/11212074 Please refer

Comment: @hongdevelop I saw that question, however, I already had the code which was there as solution, but I still have this error

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if create app bundle, it builds without errors, it doesn't solve problem with apk, but can be reasonable workaround.